When performing the transiesta calculation, the device does not converge
I am attempting to perform an electronic transport calculation, where the electrode calculations are converging normally, but the device as a whole is not converging.
# This is the remaining default SIESTA options
PAO.BasisSize    SZP
XC. functional   GGA
XC.authors       PBE
MeshCutoff       300.000000 Ry
FilterCutoff     150.000000 Ry
Electronic Temperature   300 K
OccupationFunction       FD
Diag.Paralleloverk       true
SpinPolarized .TRUE.
NonCollinearSpin .FALSE.   # Spin unpolarized calculation
MinSCFIterations   3
#MaxSCFIterations   300
SCF.DM.Tolerance   0.1 
# Mixing parameters:
SCF.Mixer.Weight
0.10
SCF.Mixer.History  12
SCF.Mix. First  true
DM. UseSaveDM  true
MD. NumCGSteps 0
SaveElectrostaticPotential T
SaveHS                                 T
%include ../STRUCT DEVICE.fdf

As you can see, we have reached 1000 steps and the calculation still has not converged. Here are my SCF (Self-Consistent Field) parameters. How can I improve my calculation?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question is similar to: Transiesta with siesta version 4.1.5 not converging. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also, we can't see anything? You haven't shown anything but your fdf files.
